# ASP.NET Trace.axd File Security

Tags: asp.net, security, trace

When I use the following code in web.config to trace the application, does the tracing actually store any information in a file on the machine? I just want to make sure that information displayed in Trace.axd is not stored anywhere else for security reasons.

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="200" localOnly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using trace on an application level with the Trace.axd page does NOT write any files to disk, it is all done in memory.  So, there is no information stored on the server itself.  All information must be accessed through the Trace.axd page.